# PHP fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php

I am getting

```
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

I have below given code

```
$data ="<html><table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table></html>";
$fileName="test.xls";
$file=fopen($path.$fileName,"w");

if(fwrite($file, $data)){       
    echo $fileName;
}
```

How can I rewrite the code to fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `$path` ?

Comment: Putting an .xls on the extension isn't going to make it an excel file. Its going to write a text file.

Comment: Your open failed, you failed to check for failure, and now you're dealing with the aftermath of writing insecure code...

Comment: @BigScar it is actually perfectly to possible put an HTML table in a file with extension `.xls`. Excel will correctly show it as a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Blizz - except that some versions of Excel will complain that "the extension doesn't match the file format".... which doesn't look very professional at all to your clients

Comment: Just because Excel will read basic html markup in a file, doesn't mean you're actually creating an Excel file, simply a file that Excel is capable of reading... never forget that

Comment: @MarkBaker obviously you are right. But for all we know it suffices for what the OP needs in this situation. Perhaps using PHPExcel is massive overkill. I just wanted to point out that Excel will read the file (after perhaps complaining about it) :)

Comment: I just find it very sad having to spend 25% of my time when people complain that PHPExcel doesn't load their Excel file correctly that they're not actually trying to load an Excel file but some species of html or csv that has been misgiven an xls or xlsx extension :(

Comment: I do sympathise, believe me :) I've had plentiful of similar situations with `.gif` vs `.bmp` on a dating site I worked on eons ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is not the upgrade in PHP version, but the fact that it failed to actually open the file in question.

[`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-returnvalues) returns either a `resource` on success or `false` on failure:

```
$data ="<html><table><tr><td>test</td></tr></table></html>"; 
// Make sure we have a / or \ between the path and the filename
$fileName = rtrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "test.xls";
$file = fopen($fileName,"w");
if ($file === false) {
   echo "opening '$fileName' failed";
   exit;
}

if (fwrite($file, $data)){       
   echo $fileName;
}
```

So you need to figure out why it can't open it in the first place. Perhaps a problem with your `$path`? Does it end with a `\` (or `/` on linux)? Does the actual path exist. Is it actually set (given that it wasn't added to your code here it might just as well be empty as far as we know)

Comment: And the message: `opening the file failed` will OP help more, than the current error message?

Comment: Can I use fputs($file,$data) instead of fwrite?

Comment: Peter that won't make a difference. `fputs` is simply an alias for `fwrite`, let me update the answer with a bit more information.

Comment: Yes, it was an issue with opening file. The actual path was changed. But I failed to note that. Since the PHP upgraded, I thought it would be something related to that. Thanks!!!